# why can't I cancel pthreads while waiting on a condition, multiple times?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

In my program, pthreads are spawned and wait for conditions, and may be cancelled while waiting.  This works for a while but then stops working - the thread cannot acquire the mutex anymore.

Below is the SSCCE.  The `routine` code follows well-known canonical examples for `pthread_cond_wait`, except I don't need to check `while (`condition not true`)` before waiting, because the condition is never signaled (if I do check, the same problem appears).

For clarity, I am not including checking returns of system calls, but they are all successful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t global_lock;
pthread_cond_t global_cond;

void *routine(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&global_lock);
    printf("waiting...\n");

    /*the condition will never arrive*/
    pthread_cond_wait(&global_cond, &global_lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_lock);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;

    pthread_cond_init(&global_cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&global_lock, NULL);

    while (1) {
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, routine, NULL);

        /*
        ** give thread enough time to start waiting
        ** should perhaps have thread signal us it started waiting
        ** but this is good enough for this example
        */
        sleep(1);

        pthread_cancel(thread);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect this would print `waiting...` every second.  But it does not, it just prints it twice and that is it, third time, `routine` is not able to initially acquire the mutex.  Why??

Comment: Threads are not cancelled. If you run `ps -eLf` you will see that more and more threads are started and none are terminated. My guess is that `pthread_cond_wait` acts like cancellation point only once, when function is entered to. Setting cancellation type to `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS` "fixes" the problem (but with potential leak of resources).

Comment: @gudok  I did not include checking of returns, but they are all successful, so `pthread_cancel` succeeds.

Comment: Zero exit status of `pthread_cancel` means that cancel request was queued and nothing more. In particular, it doesn't wait until target thread terminates.

Comment: `man pthread_cond_wait`: *pthread_cond_wait  and pthread_cond_timedwait are cancellation points. If a thread is cancelled while suspended in one of these functions,  the  thread immediately  resumes  execution,  then  locks  again  the mutex argument to pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_timedwait, and finally executes the cancellation.*

Comment: @EOF please help me understand this.  I read this manpage and to me this does not make sense, because, if `pthread_cond_wait` is a cancellation point, then the mutex would be reacquired but then the thread is cancelled, so the mutex is never released.  It does not make sense to prevent release of a mutex. Why would `pthread_cond_wait` behave this way??

Comment: @gudok it seems, that to both fix this problem, and prevent "leak of resources", I should disable cancellation at the beginning of that thread,, and then only enable it (ASYNCHRONOUS) at specific points, namely, while I am not holding the mutex, and disable it again, before acquiring the mutex.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @gudok no it does not :)  never mind

Comment: @EOF never mind I do understand now, thank you

Answer (score 3):

After somethinking, I was able to fix the problem using EOF's comment.  If EOF wants to post an answer by himself, or copy and paste parts or whole of my answer, I will accept his answer.

The problem with my code is that it does not establish a "cleanup handler" for the cancellation point at `pthread_cond_wait`.  The corrected code for `routine` is as follows, and now it works as expected.

```
void cleanup_handler(void *plock) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(plock);
}

void *routine(void *arg) {
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, &global_lock);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&global_lock);
    printf("waiting...\n");

    /*the condition will never arrive*/
    pthread_cond_wait(&global_cond, &global_lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_lock);

    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Note the `pthread_cleanup_pop` call at the end. The compiler gave me troubles because I didn't call that function. (For more information about that look at the man page)